# validate http response in python

Tags: python, sockets, http

I am making a simple webserver and I have a python function for handling request like so:

```
def handle_request(client_connection):
    request = client_connection.recv(1024)
    print(request.decode())    
    http_response = """\
                        HTTP/1.1 200 OK\n
                        Hello, World!
                      """
    client_connection.sendall(http_response)
```

Now whenever I type something else on my browser(client) I still get a 200 OK response. How can I handle the `404` response?

Comment: Ar first you will need some logic to determent which caode to send and then you send that code. It shoukd be easy to adapt the the example for 200. Please also remember that 1. you are reinventing the wheel and 2. webserver are complex and your approach is very basic so far.

Comment: You need two break lines between the headers and the body here you have only one. Some headers are mandatory, as said by @KlausD. this is the hard to learn by implementing protocols

Comment: Looks like you should parse the `request`, esp. the first line, which has the format `GET /foo?bar=baz HTTP/1.1`

Answer (score 0):

## THIS IS ONE POSSIBLE WAY

Try the code neath:

```
import requests

# Getting a request: this generates an error
response = requests.get('http://www.google.com.br/error')

if response.ok:
    print('This URL is working properly!')
else:
    print('This page either does not exist or is out.')
```

Use the `.ok` attribute in order to get a OK validation/boolean.

#peace